# Codepen vs. Jsfiddle --- Why does only one of these work with Velocity.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, velocity

I'm having an issue with Velocity.

I created an animated logo for a company who I'm doing some redesign for, when I transferred it into the HTML of the site's landing page and previewed it there was no animation running. I A/Bd a lot of things, and replaced the document load call with a button to make the testing easier, then I took the functional code from the Codepen I was using and copied it into a jsfiddle, which did not function.

I checked everything, same exact settings and libraries. I've tried moving the jQuery, Velocity, and my animation code between the head and body in every variation and sequence.

http://codepen.io/JTBennett/pen/WrRwWP

Functioning

https://jsfiddle.net/6zjc98g1/1/

Not functioning

Here's the code I wrote:

```
$( ".anbutton1" ).click(function() {

  $(".anpetal").velocity(
    "transition.expandIn", 
              {stagger: 5, drag:true, duration:1000}
  ).delay(4000)

  $(".anwords").velocity(
    "transition.expandIn", 
              {stagger: 65, drag:true, duration:1000}
  ).delay(4000)

});
```

If I can get it to start working in the jsfiddle, I'll be very happy.

Comment: Read the console: `Mixed Content: The page at 'https://fiddle.jshell.net/_display/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure script 'http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/velocity/1.2.3/velocity.ui.min.js'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.`

Comment: One more reason to not use JFiddle! I use CODEPEN All the time

Comment: @LOTUSMS I personally like jsFiddle more than Codepen, since its UI and features are better than Codepen, but that is just personal opinion.

Comment: @LOTUSMS This particular issue is hardly a reason to use one over the other. HTTPS is good - it's good that JSFiddle is on HTTPS.

Comment: Nothing being tested should require security anyway. I like being able to test on the fly.

Comment: I prefer codepen simply because of the automatic refreshing whilst writing, but for the same reason I use jsfiddle in some instances.

Comment: Simple: use only Codepen. Codepen is love. Codepen is life.

Comment: @Juanjo -- my main issue here was that I was preparing this for use on a website whose environment was the same as jsfiddle's, so in this case it was actually the reason this issue was spotted and resolved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read the console:

> Mixed Content: The page at 'https://fiddle.jshell.net/_display/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure script 'http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/velocity/1.2.3/velocity.ui.min.js'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

**tl;dr**

Your jsfiddle link is hosted over HTTPS and Codepen is hosted over HTTP (not secure).

Change your script to `https://` and it will work.
https://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/bpcLn6rb/

Or if you prefer, simply load jsFiddle over HTTP and it will also work as expected.

---

[image]

Also remember to change it to `onLoad` or `onDomready` for your jQuery code to be executed correctly.

Comment: This fixed it, thanks -- it's always some silly thing like this that causes me the biggest issues.

Comment: You can't load jsfiddle over plain http now. They need to run grep on their database as this is seriously annoying.. It's also impossible to edit the broken external resource, you must add it again manually. ::FACEPALM::